# What do I do about the DLL & MANIFEST files while converting the EXE to APK?

Tags: javascript, html, apk, exe

Ok, so I have a simple HTML-JavaScript application that has some `media` queries loaded to make it fine enough for mobile screens.

Now the problem is that the DLL file and the MANIFEST file are hard dependencies for the EXE. But the converter tool will convert only the EXE file to an APK and the DLL & MANIFEST will be left out, raising an error. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Exe file is for windows. Apk are for android - i.e linux. They don't work together.

Comment: @RaniSharim But as mentioned in the question I have media queries and an `exe` to `apk` converter, but it wont take the dll and manifest files along the exe

Comment: I just dont see how that could work. But at any rate - if its c# you can use a tool like https://github.com/Fody/Costura to embed the dll in the exe, and include the manifest as an embedded resouce, and you will only have the exe and no extra files.

Comment: @RaniSharim as mentioned in the question, it is HTML-JS